# Как передать атрибут data в jquery chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chosen

Доброго времени суток!
При помощи `jquery chosen` формируется список и для каждого элемента мне необходимо передавать `data-link` атрибут, может кто то сможет подсказать, как это сделать?

Код формирующий список

```html
<div class="chosen-container">
<select class="my-chosen-select">
  <option></option>
  <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
  <option data-link="<?=$arItem['PROPERTIES']['REG']['VALUE']?>" value="<?echo $arItem["NAME"]?>" ><span><?echo ($arItem["NAME"]." (".$arItem['PROPERTIES']['REG']['VALUE'].")");?></span></option>
  <?endforeach;?>
</select>
</div>
```

Код скрипта с настройками

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".my-chosen-select").chosen({
    placeholder_text_single: "Введите ваш город",
    no_results_text: "Извините, вашего города нет в списке",
    inherit_select_classes: true,
    search_contains: true
  });
});
```

[image: сформированные мной данные]

[image: Куда нужно передать атрибут]

Comment: Не очень понятно куда хотите передавать атрибут data-link?

Comment: Ну jquery chosen на основе этого списка формирует собственный на основе маркированного списка, мне нужно что бы у элементов li в итоговом списке были атрибуты data-link из моих option

Comment: Добвал скрины для наглядности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня недавно стояла точно такая же задача: передать значение из аттрибута `option` конечному пункту списка `chosen`.

Лучшего выхода, чем редактировать несжатую версию `chosen.jquery.js` я не придумал. С другой стороны, я не увидел в этом почти ничего плохого, кроме нарушения негласных традиций. В рамках одного проекта работающие и проверенные скрипты практически не обновляются. Риск, что изменения затрутся новой версией chosen минимален. Но, на всякий случай, я добавил коммент в начале файла, в котором описал произведенные изменения, что и вам рекомендую сделать.

В общем, вот рецепт, актуальный для моей версии `Version 1.4.2`. Редактировался несжатый файл `chosen.jquery.js`.

**1**

Ищем метод `SelectParser.prototype.add_option` и внутри него первый вызов `this.parsed.push({`. Добавляем в объект, который "пушится" в массив, новый элемент. Назовем его, к примеру, `link`:

```
link: option.getAttribute('data-link'),
```

На данном участке кода `option` - это ссылка на DOM-элемент очередного `<option>` из нашего исходного селекта.

Получается примерно такой код:

```
SelectParser.prototype.add_option = function(option, group_position, group_disabled) {
  if (option.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "OPTION") {
    if (option.text !== "") {
      if (group_position != null) {
        this.parsed[group_position].children += 1;
      }
      this.parsed.push({
        link: option.getAttribute('data-link'),
        array_index: this.parsed.length,
        options_index: this.options_index,
//...
```

**2**

Находим в файле строку (в моей версии это 264 строка)

`option_el.setAttribute("data-option-array-index", option.array_index);`

На этом участке кода создается конечный пункт списка `<li>`. А наше значение из `data-link` у нас готово к использованию в переменной `option.link`.

Рядом с найденной добавляем строку

`option_el.setAttribute("data-link", option.link);`

**Готово**

На этом все) Обновляем страницу через ctrl+f5 (для очистки кеша) и проверяем. Две простых строчки в нужных местах кода и цель достигнута.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно сработало, хотя до этого я в строке ~64 заменил option.innerHTML на html: option.outerHTML, таким образов в конечный <li> передается не только текст из <option>, но и сам <option> с учетом всех атрибутов, так тоже сработало

Comment: @IvanBubliy тоже вполне достойный вариант, хорошо придумали. Хотя, немного грязновато - `option` внутри `li`... Но если работает и ничего не видно - вариант хороший.